# Php explode function returning empty values

Tags: php, file

I am trying to read data from a comma separated text file called test.txt using PHP. The file contents is as follows:

```
Sel,10,5,4
Tati,5,6,7
Vinny,10,10,10
```

I tried to read these values using a loop with fgets(), which is used to print line by line and fgets() and explode(), which are supposed to write element per element in each line.

```
<?php
    $file=fopen('test.txt','r');

    if(!$file)
    {
        echo "Error reading file";
        die;
    }

    echo"Reading Line by Line";

    while(!feof($file))
    {
          $pointer=fgets($file,4096);
          echo "<p>".$pointer."<p>";    
    }

    rewind($file);

    echo "Reading value by value per line";

    while(!feof($file))
    {
          $pointer=fgets($file,4096);
          $pieces = explode(",", $pointer);
          echo"<hr>";
          echo "<p> Name:".$pieces[0]."<p>";
          echo "<p> Grade 1:".$pieces[1]."<p>";
          echo "<p> Grade 2:".$pieces[2]."<p>";
          echo "<p> Grade 3:".$pieces[3]."<p>";
          echo"<hr>";
    }   
    fclose($file);
?>
```

However, when I use fgets() and explode() functions in php there is a  line printed with no values. This is strange, as I have only three lines in my text file and when I use fgets() without explode() it returns the values in the correct number of lines.

What is wrong in this code?

**Edit:** here is my [code](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~anselmoferreira/le_csv.txt)

Comment: is the line with no values at the beginning or end of your result? Is it possible you have a line break at the end of your text file?

Comment: If you use [SPLFileObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) and treat this csv file as a csv file, you have options too ignore empty lines

Comment: @Sean it is at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Mad i test your code and got that problem is because of `<p>` tag is not closed inside loop, So close them and your problem will solve:-**

```
<?php
$file=fopen('test.txt','r');

if(!$file)
{
    echo "Error reading file";
    die;
}

echo"Reading Line by Line";

while(!feof($file))
{
      $pointer=fgets($file,4096);
      if(strlen($pointer) !==0){
        echo "<p>".$pointer."</p>";
      }       
}

rewind($file);

echo "Reading value by value per line";

while(!feof($file))
{
      $pointer=fgets($file,4096);
      $pieces = explode(",", $pointer);
      if(strlen($pointer) !==0){
          echo"<hr>";
          echo "<p> Name:".$pieces[0]."</p>";
          echo "<p> Grade 1:".$pieces[1]."</p>";
          echo "<p> Grade 2:".$pieces[2]."</p>";
          echo "<p> Grade 3:".$pieces[3]."</p>";
          echo"<hr>";
      }
}   
fclose($file);
?>
```

**Output:- at my local PC:- http://prntscr.com/amufst**

**Note:- my text file have no empty lines in starting as well as ending.**

Comment: I repeated your code and it is still not working. I will check my cache.

Comment: How do I check if there are empty lines in my text file?

Comment: Here is the console output:

Reading Line by Line<p>Sel,10,5,4
</p><p>Tati,5,6,7
</p><p>Vinny,10,10,10
</p><p></p>Reading value by value per line<hr><p> Name:Sel</p><p> Grade 1:10</p><p> Grade 2:5</p><p> Grade 3:4
</p><hr><hr><p> Name:Tati</p><p> Grade 1:5</p><p> Grade 2:6</p><p> Grade 3:7
</p><hr><hr><p> Name:Vinny</p><p> Grade 1:10</p><p> Grade 2:10</p><p> Grade 3:10
</p><hr><hr><p> Name:</p><p> Grade 1:</p><p> Grade 2:</p><p> Grade 3:</p><hr>

Comment: lot of possibility:- `$pieces = explode(",", $pointer); if(count($pieces) <=0){empty lines}` or `$pointer=fgets($file,4096);if(strlen($pointer) ==0){empty line}`

Comment: Yes, there is a line printed with no values. I can't see anything wrong in my text file

Comment: Take my code, remove empty lines from text file, and check first by clearing cache of your browser.

Comment: I solved the issue by inserting the clause  if(strlen($pointer) !=0){show data}. I don't know why gedit and nano are inserting empty lines at the end. I can't see these empty lines. Thank you anyway.